# Standard error of difference in means: Adding variances vs. doubling the pooled variance

Tags: variance, t-test, standard-error, group-differences

My question concerns the use of two different formulas to calculate the variance/standard error for a difference in means, as for example needed for a t-test.

The textbook formula for the variance of a **difference of two random** variables is:

$Var(X-Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2 Cov(X, Y)$

Going from here, I should be able to calculate the *standard error of a difference in means* of two independent samples $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, with sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$, by adding the variances of the samples' means and taking the square-root:

$SE_{\Delta1} = \sqrt{ Var(Y_1)/n_1 + Var(Y_2)/n_2}$

However, the standard textbook approach for t-tests (which requires an estimate of the variance of the difference in means) uses a **pooled variance estimator**, a weighted arithmetic average of the two variances, defined by

$Var_{pooled} = \pi Var(Y_1) + (1-\pi) Var(Y_2)$
with $\pi$ as the weighting factor:

$\pi = \frac{n_1-1}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}$

For getting the variance of the difference, now, this pooled ("average") variance is used twice, instead of using the two actual sample variance as above. So we get to a different standard error for the difference, following this approach:

$SE_{\Delta2} = \sqrt{ Var_{pooled}/n_1 + Var_{pooled}/n_2}$

Both approaches seem reasonable, but the results differ (slightly), see the following example:

```
set.seed(123)
y1 <- rnorm(50, 12, 10)
y2 <- rnorm(70, 8,  10)

SE_diff1 <- sqrt(var(y1)/length(y1) + var(y2)/length(y2))
SE_diff1 #1.677853

pi <- (length(y1)-1) / (length(y1) + length(y2) - 2)
SE_diff2 <- sqrt((pi*var(y1) + (1-pi)*var(y2)) * (1/length(y1) + 1/length(y2)))
SE_diff2 #1.662892
```

Funny enough, `t-test()` seems to use the first variant to calculate its t values:

```
t.test(y1, y2)$statistic     #2.577737
(mean(y1)-mean(y2))/SE_diff1 #2.577737
(mean(y1)-mean(y2))/SE_diff2 #2.600928
```

So, how does it come about that going via the pooled variance is the standard way to calculate a t statistic, introduced in all textbooks and classes and online resources (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), when it is actually more complicated? My guess is I am missing something conceptual or doing some error in my derivations, and there is a good reason for it. Thanks for all clarifications!

Comment: Got it. The second approach assumes equal variances, while default in t.test() is var.equal = FALSE.

Comment: This is probably the reason for the whole divergence here? The first approach is more general then?

Comment: The statistic in the sum of variances approach doesn't actually have a t-distribution. Have you read about the Welch-Satterthwaite approximation to the distribution of the variance? (which is used in the "Welch t test")

Comment: Thank you! As I understand the W-S approximation, it is only used to approximate the degrees of freedom of the t distribution, not the statistic (or variance, or standard error) itself?

Comment: By way of clarification: The statistic doesn't have a t-distribution. The W-S approach is to identify a t-approximation that works fairly well across a variety of variance ratios (or more specifically, it's really about approximating the d.f. in the chi-square approximation for the scaled variance used in the denominator which then leads to an approximate t for the statistic overall with the same d.f.). *Given* we're using a t-approximation, what remains is the need for a formula for the d.f.

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you!